# How to install ansible 2.9+ on ubuntu 18.04 and utilize python3?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ubuntu-18.04, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to install *minimal* ansible 2.9.x on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04 LTS).

The final goal is to build new disk image (using packer) on every commit and want the process to be as fast as possible.

## Using default Ubuntu ansible

Default ansible in [bionic is 2.5.x](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ansible&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all).

This is too old, all ansible scripts are written for 2.9+.

## Using official PPA

Using [recommended way to install](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-debian) suggests adding following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main
```

and running following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ansible
```

but it still requires python2 packages:

```
$ sudo apt install ansible
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-asn1crypto
  python-cffi-backend python-crypto python-cryptography python-enum34 python-httplib2
  python-idna python-ipaddress python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-minimal
  python-paramiko python-pkg-resources python-pyasn1 python-setuptools python-six
  python-yaml python2.7 python2.7-minimal sshpass
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python-crypto-doc python-cryptography-doc
  python-cryptography-vectors python-enum34-doc python-jinja2-doc python-gssapi
  python-setuptools-doc python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ansible libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python
  python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend python-crypto python-cryptography python-enum34
  python-httplib2 python-idna python-ipaddress python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-minimal python-paramiko python-pkg-resources python-pyasn1 python-setuptools
  python-six python-yaml python2.7 python2.7-minimal sshpass
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 83.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

## Using pip

This is my current approach but installing pip3 and then [installing ansible via pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip) is another extra step:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential cpp cpp-7 dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0
  linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-crypto python3-dev python3-distutils python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-lib2to3
  python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-xdg python3.6-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-7-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-7-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc bzr libstdc++-7-doc make-doc python-crypto-doc gnome-keyring libkf5wallet-bin gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 python-secretstorage-doc python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential cpp cpp-7 dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0
  linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-crypto python3-dev python3-distutils python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-lib2to3 python3-pip
  python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-xdg python3.6-dev
0 upgraded, 57 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 85.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 248 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

...which adds unnecessary time to the packer process :(

## Any hints?

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with python3 already installed and ansible can be easily configured to use python3.
Does anyone know a way how to install ansible 2.9 without the need to install python2 or pip3?

Comment: Is it really that problematic to install pip3 first? `apt install python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel --yes --quiet; pip3 install ansible` seems as a minimal effort, especially given that Ansible 2.9 was released 1.5 years after 18.04 was released.

Comment: okay there is an issue for that: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57342

Comment: @00 well this is actually a problem. installing pip3 wants `248 MB of additional disk space`. Updated the question to show the pip3 requirements.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem. In my case was mandatory to be in 2.9.+ because of AWX requirements ... If you are in Ubuntu 18.04 you can follow these steps:

```sh
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install ansible
```

That's it.

```sh
$ ansible --version
  |___ ansible 2.9.7
```

Note: I recommend you to ask this kind of questions in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This still installs python2.

Comment: @IkarPohorský what is the output of `$ sudo apt search ansible`

Comment: there is `ansible/bionic 2.9.7-1ppa~bionic all` but my question is all about installing ansible _without the need to install python2.7_ which is no longer developed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the [issue](http://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57342), it is currently recommended for Ubuntu users to use the Debian repository. You can download it directly [here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/ansible/download), and install the downloaded **deb** package using

```
sudo apt-get install ./ansible_x.y.z_all.deb
```

This will install ansible without installing python2.
I have successfully tested this on Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue. When I used

`sudo apt install ansible`

ansible was installed with Python 2.7.x

I uninstalled everything and installed ansible using pip. Now, when I do ansible --version I get

ansible 2.9.11
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
python version = 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) [GCC 8.4.0]

Answer (score 1):

I have recompiled the focal version of ansible (which uses python3) against bionic and published that in [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Er0lf/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages).  There were only [minimal changes](https://launchpad.net/%7Er0lf/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/ansible_2.9.6+dfsg-1_2.9.6+dfsg-1rl1.diff.gz) necessary.  You can use only the [package in question](https://launchpad.net/%7Er0lf/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/ansible_2.9.6+dfsg-1rl1_all.deb) instead of enabling the entire PPA.  You will end up with ansible 2.9.6.

Answer (score 0):

To install Ansible version 2.9 on Ubuntu 18 04:

Check if you have already a repostory configured:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu focal main
```

This repository above does not install the 2.9 anymore, instead, use:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-2.9/ubuntu focal main
```

If you do not have any repository of http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible

Add a new file to: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-2.9/ubuntu focal main
```

Run (Check if the order of the repositories are good)

```
sudo apt update
```

Install ansible:

```
sudo apt install ansible
```

Check version:

```
ansible --version
```